# Local development with Google App Engine go111 using dev_appserver is slow

Tags: go, google-app-engine, dev-appserver

I am locally running a GAE go111 program using dev_appserver.py on a reasonably fast Windows10 desktop.  I have to use dev_appserver as I'm running in classic compatibility mode by calling

```
appengine.Main()
```

I have an end point that I install using

```
http.HandleFunc("/TC/", handleTestConnection)
```

This endpoint has no code in it

```
func handleTestConnection(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
}
```

Each time I try to access this endpoint using...

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/TC/
```

...it takes ~2 seconds to respond.  This happens on all endpoints regardless of warmup or complexity.  This is not a first run problem, it will happen each time I call the endpoint.

The logs from dev_appserver are as follows...

```
DEBUG    2021-09-24 19:14:10,460 module.py:1499] Dispatching request to <Instance 9cca95d2ec7bedafddd44639c7e2cd139bfc: 0/8, total: 1> after 0.0000s pending
DEBUG    2021-09-24 19:14:12,490 <string>:134] API server executing remote_api_pb.Request: 
service_name: "logservice"
method: "Flush"
request: "\n\000"
request_id: "uumGeJVDum"
DEBUG    2021-09-24 19:14:12,492 <string>:194] API server responding with remote_api_pb.Response:
DEBUG    2021-09-24 19:14:12,492 <string>:493] Handled logservice.Flush in 0.0020
DEBUG    2021-09-24 19:14:12,493 instance.py:410] Request handled by <Instance 9cca95d2ec7bedafddd44639c7e2cd139bfc: 1/8, total: 2> in 2.0320s
INFO     2021-09-24 19:14:12,493 module.py:883] default: "GET /TC/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2021-09-24 19:14:12,516 module.py:883] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150
```

Everything works correctly and fast once deployed to a Google app engine server, it's just local development that is slow.

I have tried numerous options of dev_appserver including...

```
--logs_path
--dev_appserver_log_level
--log_level
--threadsafe_override
--max_module_instances
--datastore_consistency_policy
--enable_host_checking
```

I have tried running natively using

```
go run .
```

But as this is in classic compatibility mode this does not work.

I have tried turning off virus checkers / firewalls.  Other browsers. Using localhost.  Other ports.  3 completely different desktops.  Using host=0.0.0.0 then my local ip.  All result in the same delay.

Has anyone hit and solved this problem?

Comment: I found a link to [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/best-practices-for-app-engine-startup-time-google-cloud-performance-atlas) for app engine which explains possible reasons why it might be slower that it should. 
There is also a link to [this](youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIivdWyY5sqK5zce0-fd1Vam7oPY-s_8X) youtube list which also explains some common issues.  

If this doesn't help please specify how fast do you expect it to be, and what the classic compatibility mode is, I wasn't able to find any information regarding that in Google App Engine.

Comment: @LluísMuñoz many thanks for your reply.  AFAICS these links talk about performance when deployed to a real AppEngine server.  My problem is with local development when using dev_appserver.  My deployed server is blindingly fast, the endpoint in my question replies in milliseconds and I expect that my local development server should closely match that.  The appengine.Main() was documented in the migration to go 1.11 but now here is the only reference I can find. 
 https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/go-differences#package-main

Comment: Could you please share a code snippet or reproduction steps to reproduce your issue?  

I've tried to reproduce it by running [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/quickstart#download_the_hello_world_app) code in the Cloud Console using the local development as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/tools/local-devserver-command). 
Then I called it using [Apache Benchmark](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) `ab -n 1000 -c 10 MY_URL` but everything worked fine.